Formula for gaps between primes
The twin prime conjecture refers to:
$$
   \liminf_{n\to \infty}\; p_{n+1} - p_{n} = 2.
 $$
By  reasoning I arrive at the following simple formula for gaps between primes:
\begin{align}   
        p_{n+1}-p_{n}
        & = \frac{p_{n+1}^{2}-p_{n}^{2}}{p_{n+1}+p_{n}}=2 \\
        & \Rightarrow (p_{n}+h)^{2}-p_{n}^{2} =2(2p_{n}+h)\\        
        & \Rightarrow h^{2}+2p_{n}h =2h+4p_{n}\\
        & \Rightarrow \frac{h^{2}-2h}{2}+p_{n}h =2p_{n}\\
        & \Rightarrow p_{n} < p_{n}+h < 2p_{n} \le p_{n}h \le\frac{h^{2}-2h}{2}+p_{n}h\\          
        & \Rightarrow p_{n} < p_{n}+h < 2p_{n} \le \frac{h^{2}-2h}{2}+p_{n}\\   
        & \Rightarrow \frac{h^{2}-2h}{2} \le p_{n}-2\\
        & \Rightarrow (h-\sqrt{2})^{2}\le 2p_{n}-2\\
        & \Rightarrow (h-\sqrt{2})^{2}< 2p_{n} \\
        & \Rightarrow h < \sqrt{2p_{n}}+\sqrt{2}
\end{align}
so:
$$
p_{n+1} - p_{n} < \sqrt{2p_{n}}+\sqrt{2}
$$
or:
$$
p_{n+1} <  p_{n} + \sqrt{2p_{n}}+\sqrt{2}.
$$
It's a simple conclusion, and one that is stronger and more valid than the Bertrand's postulate.
For example, we often use $[\sqrt{x},x]$ as a judgment and determination of prime number interval, and the above inference can directly give the answer.
I want to ask, is this conclusion correct?
By the way, this formula only holds if the twin prime conjecture holds.

Welcome to MO!  Your bound $p_{n + 1} < p_n + \sqrt{2p_n} + \sqrt2$ came from $p_{n + 1} = p_n + 2$, which is much simpler, so I'm not sure what you gained.  As you say, you have only proven the former inequality when $(p_n, p_{n + 1})$ are twin primes.  By comparison, Bertrand's postulate is for arbirary primes.

@LSpice Thank. My main goal is to prove that there must be a prime number in the interval [p~p+$\sqrt{2p}+\sqrt{2}$ ], which is strong than there must be a prime number in the interval [p~2p].

Re, but you have proven this only for $p$ the first of a pair of twin primes, where it is obvious.

Re. I think this point can be used as a basis for the judgment of twin prime numbers, if there is no prime number in the interval [p~$p+\sqrt{2p}+\sqrt{2}$], , it is proved that the twin prime number is false.

Wayne: what @LSpice is saying is, what you have proved is that if $p_{n+1}-p_n=2$ then $p_{n+1}-p_n<\sqrt{2p_n}+\sqrt{2}$. This is not going to buy you anything at all.

Also posted to, and closed on, math.stackexchange, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4977101/formula-of-gaps-between-primes – without any notice to either site of its posting to the other, a violation of terms of both sites.

Such conjectures are known in the literature. For example, Andrica's conjecture.
It is known that under the Riemann Hypothesis one has $p_{n+1} - p_n = O(\sqrt{p_n} \log p_n)$. The best unconditional result of this sort is due to Baker, Harman, and Pintz, who showed that there is always a prime in the interval $[x, x + x^{0.525})$ for $x$ sufficiently large.
